# Call a Modal form view in codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, bootstrap-modal

I have a View called Items and inside it i want to use this button to show a Modal form in another View.

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url('items/Show/'.$value['id']); ?>" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm edit btn-orange"   data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target=".bs-example-modal-center"  title="View">
                                                <i class="fas fa-eye "></i>
                                            </a>
```

this is the function in Items controller than will load data to the form

```
function Show($id){

        if (isset($id)){
            
            $this->load->model('Itemo');
            $data['view']=$this->Itemo->Edit_items($id);
            $this->load->view('user/Dashboard/header');
            $this->load->view('user/Dashboard/View',$data);
            $this->load->view('user/Dashboard/footer');

        }else{

            redirect('/items/List_cat', 'refresh');

        }


        }
```

and this is the View which contains the modal form Called View

```
<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-center" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                                                <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
                                                    <div class="modal-content">
                                                        <div class="modal-header">
                                                            <h5 class="modal-title">Center modal</h5>
                                                            <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal"
                                                                aria-label="Close"></button>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="modal-body">
                                                            <!-- /.data loaded here-->
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <!-- /.modal-content -->
                                                </div>
                                                <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
                                            </div>
                                            <!-- /.modal -->
                                        </div>
```

But when i click on the button nothing shows

Comment: Just guessing here:
your Modal is an anchor. by default this would redirect to a new page but you maybe prevented - or your bootstrap is doing that for you.

Does bootstrap modal de an ajax call to get the modal-content?
Maybe you have to store the result first:
$data=$this->load->view('pagename',$datapassed, TRUE);
than you can echo it, eg with $this->set_output($data);

Comment: the problem is the view doesnt show at all , normally i want that form to pop up and it doesnt

Answer (score 0):

Your Show function isn't returning anything in ajax context.

I suggest this:

1. Add an id to the modal toggler (eg: `id="open-modal"`)
2. Make show function return the view with `echo`

```php
    function Show($id){

        if (isset($id)){
            
            $this->load->model('Itemo');
            $data['view']=$this->Itemo->Edit_items($id);
            $view=$this->load->view('user/Dashboard/header', null, true);
            $view.=$this->load->view('user/Dashboard/View',$data, true);
            $view.=$this->load->view('user/Dashboard/footer', null, true);
            echo $view;
        }else{
    
            redirect('/items/List_cat', 'refresh');
    
        }
    
    
        }
```

3. An AJAX call to fill the modal content:

```js
    <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#open-modal').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        let url = $(this).attr('href');
        $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(data){
          $('.modal-body').html(data);
        },
        error: function(err){
          console.log('An error occured', err);
        }
       });
      });
    </script>
```